# How to completely remove Grid horizontal bar lines in apexcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

[image: graph current image with grid bar type lines]

Here I have marked bar lines in line graph in red color, any suggestions how to remove it or make it transparent so that it matches background color, I tried giving background "transparent" but that is not working.

Note: I'm using theme "dark" in options